# Protecting encryption key in an unmanaged package

Tags: security

How do I protect an encryption key, a private AES-256 key (so that no one can access it including admins) within salesforce? I understand that this can be done using a managed package and installing that package (and thereby using the key) in the enterprise edition.

But is it possible to do it without having to create a managed package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that this key is for use with the Apex `Crypto` class, not Shield Platform Encryption.

**The** Salesforce-recommended way to obtain secure secret storage other than URL parameters is a Protected Custom Setting or Protected Custom Metadata in a managed package, which can be accessed only by Apex within that package. See [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets#How_do_I_protect_my_application.3F_2) for more.

Named Credentials are the other applicable secret-storage mechanism, only where callout authentication is in play - i.e. not Apex Crypto.

All other solutions will simply be security through obscurity. You cannot prevent your System Administrators from accessing unprotected Custom Settings, Custom Metadata, or the other key locations where you might store this data.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, correct. It is for the Crypto class. When you say it is the "Salesforce-recommended" practice, is there any literature on the Salesforce documentation site? If yes, can you please link to it?

Comment: Absolutely. See the link I added.